# Converting Date.valueof primitive to Ruby

Tags: c++, ruby, zabbix

Im currently porting some c++ code to ruby, i'm returning a date value from zabbix which comes back as a date primitive.

The current code for doing this is:

`Math.round(((new Date().valueOf()) - parseInt(result[0].value) * 1000) / 86400000)`

I got this so far:

`(result[0]['value'].to_i*1000) / 86400000).round`

Not sure how to port `new Date().valueOf()`

Comment: what does `new Date().valueOf()` return and what should the final format be?

Comment: Date.valueof returns something like "1441972284808", the final format should be a number of days

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy What number of days do you need? From the start of the year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1441972284808` looks like Unix Timestamp in milliseconds, so you can try this:

```
time = Time.at(1441972284808 / 1000.0)
# => 2015-09-11 16:51:24 +0500
time.strftime('%j') # days quantity from start of the year
# => "254"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt need days from start of year so `time.day` worked fine :)